# UICollectionView overlapping labels

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a collectionview and the first data load is working fine.  The problem occurs when the data is load a second time the labels overlaps because the old labels appear to still exist.
Below is my collectionview code, thanks in advance.

```
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let customCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
                customCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                customCell.layer.borderWidth = 1


    // changed these lines here
                if cellsLabels[indexPath.row] != nil {
                    customCell.willRemoveSubview(cellsLabels[indexPath.row]!)
                }
    //to these lines here and the problem was solved
            let maybe = customCell.subviews

            for i in 0 ..< maybe.count {
                maybe[i].removeFromSuperview()
            }
                let c

ommentLabel = UILabel()
            commentLabel.text = commentsArray[indexPath.row]
            commentLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 200, height: 30)
            customCell.addSubview(commentLabel)

            self.cellsLabels[indexPath.row] = commentLabel

            if indexPath.row == commentLoadTracker*10 - 1 {
                print("working doomfist")
            }

            return customCell
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return commentsArray.count
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            var cellSize = CGSize()
            cellSize.width = self.commentView.frame.width
            cellSize.height = 100
            return cellSize
        }
```

Comment: You don't really need to update the question with your results. It may take away from the clarity of the question. Also, you can loop through the subviews like this: `for view in customCell.subviews`, then you don't have to create a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> customCell.willRemoveSubview

You are calling `willRemoveSubiew` instead of `removeFromSuperview`

```
if cellsLabels[indexPath.row] != nil {
    cellsLabels[indexPath.row]!.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

There is no need to call `willRemoveSubview`, UIKit calls it for you, it only exists so that it can be

> Overridden by subclasses to perform additional actions before subviews are removed from the view.

Comment: AND THAN YOU!  Problem solved, there was another minor issue but essentially mucked that up thanks for the catch!